# How to create data migrations with Drizzle ORM?

Tags: typescript, orm, database-migration, drizzle

I can use Drizzle kit to create and run schema changes to my database, but I don't know how to make data migrations with it. I've got experience from Django where you can manually create migration files which also support custom Python code. There you can run whatever code/SQL etc. to insert data in to the db. It also makes sure that the (data) migration is being run only once.

How can I achieve this with Drizzle? The `drizzle-kit generate:pg` checks only for schema changes so I can't add only data with it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this from the [doc](https://orm.drizzle.team/kit-docs/commands).

```
drizzle-kit generate:pg --custom
```

Comment: This is actually quite nice. I was hoping there was a way to include maybe even custom typescript in the data migrations (like Django ORM migrations does), BUT this is way better than nothing and I had missed this option altogether. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. As a tool in an early stage, Drizzle has a lot to improve.

Answer (score 0):

you probably got this resolved but you need to run this script

```js
node -r esbuild-register src/db/index.ts
```

and in the index.ts file, have somethine like this :

```js
import { drizzle, PostgresJsDatabase } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js';
import { migrate } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js/migrator';
import postgres from 'postgres';

console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || '';
const migrationsClient = postgres(connectionString, {
    max: 1,
});
const db = drizzle(migrationsClient);
migrate(db, { migrationsFolder: 'drizzle' });
```

Comment: I’m actually trying to find a solution where I could write a data migration file, run ”migrate” and then if I run ”migrate” again it wouldn’t run that file again. So the ORM would know it has already been exrcuted. Like Drizzle has for schema changes.